# Define a DCG in Prolog for bit strings practice problem

Tags: prolog, dcg

Before our Prolog final exam soon, I got some practice questions and I am stuck on one:

> For each integer n > 0,
> let Ln := {s ∈ {0, 1}+ | s ends in a string from 1(0 + 1)n−1}
> be the set of bit-strings whose n-th to the last bit is 1. That is, Ln is described by the regular expression (0 + 1)∗1(0 + 1)n−1.

> Define a DCG for the 3-ary predicate s/3 such that s(n,s,[]) is true exactly if s encodes a string in Ln.

I tried for a while to get this, but I am unsure what to do, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Do you know how to write DCGs in general? Do you understand regular expressions? Can you write a DCG for the regular expression `(0 + 1)*`?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I am unsure where to start. I try for 5 mins at a time and i get stuck on where i could start to solve the question, I know how to write DCG;s in general and i also understand regular expressions but i don't know how to write a DCG for (0 + 1)*

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie how would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a DCG for `(0 + 1)*`:

```
zero_or_one -->
    [0].
zero_or_one -->
    [1].

many_zero_or_one -->
    [].
many_zero_or_one -->
    zero_or_one,
    many_zero_or_one.
```

Comment: the "many" in "many_zero_or_one" is a bit misleading but anyway.... you can generally use `call` in DCGs to model such patterns, as in: `bit --> [0]. bit --> [1]. star(_) --> []. star(P) --> call(P), star(P).`. Try now calling `?- length(L, _), phrase(star(bit), L).`

Comment: You can of course model the whole thing to look even more like the problem statement. For example, if you define `+` and `*` as: `+(A, B) --> [A] | [B]. *(P) --> [] | call(P), *(P).` then you can directly write: `?- length(L, _), phrase(*(+(0, 1)), L).`

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to make it *look* like the regular expression you showed, just for funzies. I will not define operators and instead "parse" the regex to something that Prolog can read without new operator definitions (I am not even sure if you can make it work just with redefining operators, maybe it isn't possible). So I will define a `+//2` for "or" and `*//1` for "0 or more repetitions" and `n//2` for "n repetitions".

```
+(A, B) --> [A] | [B].
*(P) --> [] | call(P), *(P).
n(P, N) --> { length(L, N) }, n_1(L, P).
n_1([], _) --> [].
n_1([_|L], P) --> call(P), n_1(L, P).
```

With those available I can write a query that roughly resembles your problem statement:

```
?- length(L, _), phrase(( *(+(0,1)), [1], n(+(0,1), 1) ), L).
L = [1, 0] ;
L = [1, 1] ;
L = [0, 1, 0] ;
L = [0, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 0] ;
L = [1, 1, 1] ;
L = [0, 0, 1, 0] ;
L = [0, 0, 1, 1] ;
L = [0, 1, 1, 0] . % it goes on
```

Note that here I set the *n* to be equal to 2, so in `n//2` I am using 2 - 1 = 1.

EDIT: I noticed that the `*//1` I defined is just a special case of `n//2`. So you can actually do this:

```
?- phrase(n(+(0,1), N), L).
N = 0,
L = [] ;
N = 1,
L = [0] ;
N = 1,
L = [1] ;
N = 2,
L = [0, 0] ;
N = 2,
L = [0, 1] ;
N = 2,
L = [1, 0] ;
N = 2,
L = [1, 1] ;
N = 3,
L = [0, 0, 0] .
```

In other words, you can leave the N argument a free variable and you will get strings of increasing length, with the length in N.

Comment: That's a nice solution!